# Separating alleles for 'bcftools merge' when ploidy >2

Tags: bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format, bcftools, vcftools

I am a beginner.

I want to merge my annotated .vcf files to look at alll SNPs in Variant Effect Predictor. Some of my .vcf files are ploidy 3, 4 and 5. They were separated out before variant calling.

`bcftools merge` doesn't work when ploidy is greater than 2. So I'm trying to separate out all haplotypes with the workaround on the FAQ page:

"Note that the program only works with ploidy 1 or 2, so if defined as Number=G and the ploidy is bigger, the program will fail. If the tag is not important for your analysis, a quick and dirty workaround is to remove the tag from the VCF completely (`bcftools annotate -x TAG`)."

I was hoping to use this with my list file (is there a way to do this?) but I couldn't find a way. Instead I used ChatGPT to help write a script (I'm sorry):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change to the working directory for output .vcf.gz files
cd /nesi/nobackup/vuw03939/combined_vcf/

# Display the current directory path for troubleshooting
pwd

# Path to the directory containing your .vcf.gz files
vcf_dir="../nextflow/liti_3iploid/sarek_anno_3ploid_snpeff/annotation"

# Output directory for modified files
output_dir="./combined_3ploid"
mkdir -p "$output_dir"

# List of .vcf.gz files
file_list="3ploid.list"

# Display the file list for troubleshooting
echo "Files to process:"
cat "$file_list"

# Loop through each file in the list and remove all tags
while IFS= read -r vcf_file || [ -n "$vcf_file" ]; do
# Extract just the filename without the directory path
filename=$(basename "$vcf_file")

# Generate the output file name by removing the ".vcf.gz" extension and adding "_removed.vcf.gz"
output_file="${filename%.vcf.gz}_removed.vcf.gz"

# Use BCFTools to remove all tags
bcftools annotate -x INFO -O z -o "${output_dir}/${output_file}" "${vcf_dir}/${vcf_file}"

# Construct the path to the corresponding TBI file using the directory of the VCF file
tbi_file="${vcf_dir}/${vcf_file}.tbi"

# Check if the corresponding TBI file exists and then copy it
if [ -e "$tbi_file" ]; then
    cp "$tbi_file" "${output_dir}/${output_file}.tbi"
else
    echo "Warning: ${tbi_file} file not found"
fi
done < "$file_list"
```

This achieves the removal of, in this case, `INFO` - which works. I have tried other options like `TAG` (get error: `No matching tag in -x TAG`) and `FORMAT/PL`, which also seems to work okay. The last part copies over the index files to the new directory.

But when I go to merge these .vcf files:

`bcftools merge combined_3ploid/*.gz -Ov -o combined_3ploid.vcf`

I get the error:
`[E::get_intv] Failed to parse TBX_VCF, was wrong -p [type] used?`

Followed by `The offending line was:`

lots of
`"moved.vcf.gz ../nextflow/liti_3iploid/sarek_anno_3ploid_snpeff/annotation/./ABV/ABV.haplotypecaller_snpEff.ann.vcf.gz; Date=Thu Mar  7 15:56:42 2024"`

and a few
`"G      GTTA    3397.98 .       AC=1;AF=0.333;AN=3;BaseQRankSum=-1.37;DP=333;FS=2.861;MLEAC=1;MLEAF=0.333;MQ=60;MQRankSum=0;QD=13.17;ReadPosRankSum=-1.148;SOR=0.822;ANN=GTTA|disruptive_inframe_insertion|MODERATE|URE2|YNL229C|transcript|YNL229C_mRNA|protein_coding|1/1|c.144_146dupTAA|p.Asn49dup|146/1065|146/1065|49/354||,GTTA|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|PDR16|YNL231C|transcript|YNL231C_mRNA|protein_coding||c.-3016_-3014dupTAA|||||3014|,GTTA|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|ELA1|YNL230C|transcript|YNL230C_mRNA|protein_coding||c.-1396_-1394dupTAA|||||1394|,GTTA|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|YNL228W|YNL228W|transcript|YNL228W_mRNA|protein_coding||c.-590_-589insTTA|||||589|,GTTA|upstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|YNL226W|YNL226W|transcript|YNL226W_mRNA|protein_coding||c.-2184_-2183insTTA|||||2183|,GTTA|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|CSL4|YNL232W|transcript|YNL232W_mRNA|protein_coding||c.*4254_*4255insTTA|||||4255|,GTTA|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|JJJ1|YNL227C|transcript|YNL227C_mRNA|protein_coding||c.*601_*603dupTAA|||||603|,GTTA|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|CNM67|YNL225C|transcript|YNL225C_mRNA|protein_coding||c.*2666_*2668dupTAA|||||2668|,GTTA|downstream_gene_variant|MODIFIER|SQS1|YNL224C|transcript|YNL224C_mRNA|protein_coding||c.*4738_*4740dupTAA|||||4740|        GT:AD:DP:GQ     0/0/1:165,93:258:99"`

Besides the part about the .vcf being moved, the other "offending lines" seem quite random.

Here's my dirty laundry, and again I am pretty new to all of this - I'm sure there are many errors in my approach, so I look forward to your input, and/or ideas about alternative workarounds.

This is above. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Is the file `ABV.haplotypecaller_snpEff.ann.vcf.gz` gzip'ed, or bgzip'ed? Have you run tabix on the file? I suspect the `Failed to parse TBX_VCF, was wrong -p [type] used?` refers to the 'tabix' step, where you typically specify  the filetype, e.g. `tabix -p "vcf" ABV.haplotypecaller_snpEff.ann.vcf.gz`. Does that make sense? Also, this type of domain-specific question is better suited to https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ and will likely be closed here, as it's not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I got around this error by generating new index files with "bcftools index".

Comment: Glad you solved your problem @Isaac :)